# A question about the steady state solution of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am working on solving the following differential equations:

$$ \begin{align}
y_1'(t) &= g - b y_1(t)\\
y_2'(t) &= by_1(t)
\end{align}$$

with initial conditions $y_1 (0) = y_2(0) = 0$.

First, I calculated the stationary solutions. **Can you tell me if this is correct?**

Stationary means the rate of change is zero i.e.:

$$ \begin{align}
y_1'(t) &= 0 =  g - b y_1(t)\\
y_2'(t) &= 0 = by_1(t)
\end{align}$$

From equation $1$ we get

$$ y_1(t) = \frac{g}{b}$$

and substituting this into the second equation, gives $y_2'(t) = g $. Integrating on both sides yields:

$$ y_2 (t) = gt + C$$

for some constant $C$. Using the initial conditions, we see that $C=0$, hence $y_2(t) = gt$.

So the stationary solutions are:

$$ \begin{align}
y_1(t) &=\frac{g}{b}\\
y_2(t) &= gt
\end{align}$$

---

Next, since this system is inhomogeneous, I have to first determine the solution of the corresponding homogeneous system:

$$ \begin{align}
y_1'(t) &=  - b y_1(t)\\
y_2'(t) &=  by_1(t)
\end{align}$$

I did this by first solving equation 1 and then using the result to solve equation 2: $\frac{dy_1}{dt} = - by_1$ so that $\frac{dy_1}{ y_1} = -b$. Integrating on both sides and then taking the exponential yields:

$$ \begin{align}
\ln (y_1) &= -bt + K\\
y_1(t) &= C e^{-bt} 
\end{align}$$

Now this is where things get a little weird: One of the initial conditions is $y_1(0) = 0$ so this would give $C=0$ and therefore $y_1(t) = 0$. **What am I doing wrong?**

---

I have an example solution to this problem in which they avoid the problem of getting $y_1(t) = 0$ by adding the stationary solution to the ansatz:

$$y_1(t) = C e^{-bt} + \frac{g}{b}$$

I've not seen this approach before.

**Do I in general always have to add the stationary solution to the ansatz for the homogeneous system? Or in which case is this the correct approach to take?**

Comment: Note that a stationary solution cannot depend on $t$

Comment: @user619894 Ok. Right. How do I get the correct answer for $y_2$?

Comment: don't think there is a stationary solution unless special values of the parameters